# Determining a faster/better approach for finding the pairs with minimum difference in an array

Tags: time-complexity, c++

Wondering which approach is faster in terms of time complexity. In short, is having a single loop that clears out the vector every time there's a difference lesser than the minimum so far faster than having two separate loops: first determines the minimum difference, second appends the corresponding elements with minimum difference to the vector.

**First approach: (one loop)**

```
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> minDiffElements(std::vector<int>& arr) 
    {
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> ans;
        sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());

        int minDiff = INT_MAX;

        for (int i=1; i<arr.size(); i++)
        {
            int diff = arr[i] - arr[i-1];

            if (diff < minDiff)
            {
                ans = {{arr[i-1], arr[i]}}; // reinitialize the array
                minDiff = diff;
            }
            else if (diff == minDiff)
            {
                ans.push_back( {arr[i-1], arr[i]} );
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
```

**Second approach: (two loops)**

```
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> minDiffElements(std::vector<int>& arr) 
    {
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> ans;
        sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
            
        int minDiff = INT_MAX;
        
        for (int i=1; i<arr.size(); i++)
        {
            int diff = arr[i] - arr[i-1];
            if (diff < minDiff)
            {
                minDiff = diff;
            }
        }
        
        for (int i=1; i<arr.size(); i++)
        {
            int diff = arr[i] - arr[i-1];
            if (diff == minDiff)
            {
                ans.push_back({arr[i-1], arr[i]});
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
```

Sample:

```
input:  [-1000000, 1000000]
output: [[-1000000,1000000]]

input:  [1,9,10,15,16]
output: [[9,10],[15,16]]
```

Comment: My array has two elements, INT_MIN and INT_MAX. What happens?

Comment: Give us the time for sorting, the time for adding a number to an array of k elements, and the time for erasing an array of k elements.

Comment: You are asking to find *a* pair, but seem to be willing to keep all such pairs !?

Comment: @gnasher729 well, the diff b/w INT_MAX and INT_MIN would end up in an array itself cause there's no other pair to compare to anyways?

Comment: What’s the difference between int_max and min? It doesn’t fit into an Int.

Comment: true. we can consider values [-10^6, 10^6]

Answer (score 0):

Assume an array of $n$ elements, containing $k$ groups with equidistant pairs, of decreasing difference, each including $m_k$ pairs.

The first version performs $n-1$ comparisons and $k$ array initializations and $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k m_i$ `push_back`. The worst case is $n-1$ comparisons and $k$ initializations plus $n-1$ `push_back`.

The second version performs $n-1$ comparisons, then $n$ comparisons and $m_k$ `push_back`. The worst case is $2n-1$ comparisons, $1$ initialization and $n-1$  `push_back`.

The best cases involve both a single initialization and a single `push_back`. Without more information, the expected cases are unknown. That's about all that can be said.